# Type mismatch: cannot convert from Cursor to String[] error

Tags: java

```
public Cursor fetchThePassword(long paramLong) throws SQLException {
    SQLiteDatabase localSQLiteDatabase = this.db;
    String[] localObject = new String[2];
    localObject[0] = "id";
    localObject[1] = "pass";
    localObject = localSQLiteDatabase.query(true, "register", localObject, "id=" +aramLong, null, null, null, null, null);
    if (localObject != null)
        ((Cursor)localObject).moveToFirst();  
    return localObject; 

 }
```

Comment: Boy, what would the error message mean..

Comment: You do realize you are trying to stuff a cursor (your result set) into a String array?  `String[] localObject = new String[2];`

Comment: I think the main problem is that you cannot convert from Cursor to String[]... but that's just a guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what you try to do there exactly but my best guess is the following:

```
public String fetchThePassword(long paramLong) throws SQLException {
    SQLiteDatabase localSQLiteDatabase = this.db;
    String[] columns = new String[] { "pass" };
    Cursor cursor = localSQLiteDatabase.query(true, "register", columns, "id=" + paramLong,
            null, null, null, null, null);

    String result = null;
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        // value from the pass column 
        result = cursor.getString(0);
    }
    cursor.close();
    // result is either the pass or null
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You create a String-array `localObject` and cast it to a `Cursor`. This can't work.

```
 ((Cursor)localObject).moveToFirst();
```